# Firebase's version of SQL Injection

Tags: firebase, code-injection

Using firebase for the first time after a strong background of SQL. I'm used to using functions like `addslashes()` to sanitize user input into queries.

Is there any standard way of doing the similar thing with Firebase lookups?

For example:

```
// expected a key, not a path
var userProvidedKey = "3/malicious"

// will not be a ref to what I expect
var ref = firebase.database().ref(`something/${userProvidedKey}`)
```

I don't know how malicious it can be for a user to be able to search further down in a ref, but maybe this problem is solved? Or do I need to `.split('/').shift()` any inputs that I receive?

Note: Using the JS SDK for my examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input/output should always be sanitized and validated before entering the database.

Firebase provides [security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and [data validation checks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data) to be used in your application. Firebase also provides rules in its database to determine which users have write/read access to which data in the database.

For more information read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) about the Firebase realtime database.

Found this thread [Adding Firebase data, dots and forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132867/adding-firebase-data-dots-and-forward-slashes) that may answer some practical questions on Firebase specific sanitation.