# Can not insert the value for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout

If I try to insert `"Test1."` as value to `EditText`, then the app was going to be crashed. But if I removed the period(.) and retry to enter the value it is fine. Why can't I insert value with period(.). Below is my codes snippets including xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.naveenbimsara.pharmacy.MainActivity"

    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Mediname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textUri|textWebEditText|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions|textFilter|text|textPostalAddress|textEmailAddress|textEmailSubject"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.545"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.287"
        tools:text="@string/google_storage_bucket" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/insbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insert"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.691" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/availa"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.465" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AddMedicine.java**

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class AddMedicine extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "AddMedicine";

    EditText mName;
    Spinner mySpinner;
    ArrayAdapter<String>myAdapter;
    Button mInsert;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Medi medi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_medicine);
        mName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Mediname);
        mySpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.availa);

        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddMedicine.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ava));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        mInsert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.insbtn);
        medi=new Medi();
        reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Medicine");
        mInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                medi.setName(mName.getText().toString().trim());
                medi.setAvailable(mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                final String Name=mName.getText().toString().trim();
                if(Name.length()==0)
                {
                    mName.requestFocus();
                    mName.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }


                else {
                    reff.child(mName.getText().toString().trim()).setValue(medi);
                    Toast.makeText(AddMedicine.this, "Data Inserted sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Medi.java**

```
public class Medi {
    private String Name;
    private String Available;


    public Medi() {
    }

    public Medi(String name, String available) {
        Name = name;
        Available = available;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getAvailable() {
        return Available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(String available) {
        Available = available;
    }


}
```

**Logcat**

[image]

[image]

Comment: `it will generate some error` show error

Comment: Didn't generate any error

Comment: @Dilshan When your app crash you will get error message in the logcat. Can you add that here?

Comment: @Blasanka I added my logcat result

Comment: @Dilshan Kindly upload the part of your logcat that reflects the crash.

Comment: What do you mean by `If I try to insert "Test1."`? Where are you trying to insert it? Do you mean typing it directly into your code? (If so, where?) Or are you typing it in the UI after you run your app? (Again, where?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I got the point. The reason is you are trying to add your `EditText` value as a firebase database child ref. So, there some special characters you cannot use including period(.).

When dot specify without another text after dot, it will causes app to crash because dot identify as a another child node. Read [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132867/adding-firebase-data-dots-and-forward-slashes).

Followings cannot use as firebase database keys (child names):

- `.` (period)
- `$` (dollar sign)
- `[` (left square bracket)
- `]` (right square bracket)
- `#` (hash or pound sign)
- `/` (forward slash)