# How to use dot notation as a field name in Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Thank you for reading this question.
As I wrote in the title, I'm struggling using dot notation field in firebase. What I want to update is a field named '0.1'.

My code is below

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('products')
        .doc('a')
            .update({
                '0.1': FieldValue.arrayUnion(value)
            });
```

By running this, it creates a nested field like
`0　: {1: value}`
, whether I expect is a field named '0.1'.

I also tried using package `flat` but didn't work:

```
flat (0.1: FieldValue.arrayUnion(value))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `0.1` be `"0.1"`?

Comment: yes. Sorry, that was may mistake when pasting to stackoverflow. It creates a nest a when '0.1'.

Comment: It seems that dots are just not allowed in keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132867/adding-firebase-data-dots-and-forward-slashes So these should be escaped

Answer (score 0):

In field names you pass to `update` as strings the `.` is interpreted as a field separator, as shown in the documentation on [updating nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

To prevent that, you can:

- Either use the `set` method with `SetOptions(merge: true)`, since `set` doesn't interpret the `.` as a field separator.
- Or [use a `FieldPath`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldPath-class.html) to wrap the field name, which makes the database interpret the `.` as a literal character.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I eventually didn't use the . notation since it said not to use them in the official document. I still will try using the way you taught me also. Thank you so much.